# How does a do{...}while() loop work?

Tags: c#

This is my  simple calculator code  in vs2013 using  c# , what it is supposed to do is when program lads if i press  Q it should quit but it proceeds even if  i enter  Q whats wrong with approach

```
 class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            float value1, value2, result= 0; 
            char op , cont;
            Console.WriteLine("Simple Calculator"); 
        do {
               Console.WriteLine("Please enter Q to Quit or continue  "); 
                cont = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter First value  ");
                value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter Second value  ");
                value2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter  operator   ");
                op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                if (op == '+')
                {
                    result = value1 + value2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Result is : {0}", result);
                }

          }     
        while(cont!='Q');
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `cont` is asked first so yes you will have to complete the (1) loop.

Comment: The `while` condition is evaluated only when the block inside the `do` finishes, not whenever the variable change its value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want immediate exit, you **need to break immediately**. For that put the following line

```
if (cont == 'Q')
    break;
```

after your code,

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Q to Quit or continue  "); 
cont = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an infinite loop that breaks on condition:

```
while (true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter Q to Quit or continue  ");
  cont = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
  if (cont == 'Q') break;
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter First value  ");
  value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter Second value  ");
  value2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter  operator   ");
  op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
  if (op == '+')
  {
    result = value1 + value2;
    Console.WriteLine("Result is : {0}", result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by reading a complete line (as a string) and return early on 'Q' as first character.

After that, you can retrieve the characters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

A do-while loops for the one time irrespective of the condition!!!! 
So for exiting, put an additional condition right after reading the value into cont

Answer (score 0):

First of all the phrase in this WriteLine call

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Q to Quit or continue  ");
```

is very confusing. For example I do not understand what I should enter that to continue the calculations.

Secondly you pass through the loop even if a user enters 'Q'.

At least you have to check variable `cont` at once it was entered and if it is equal to 'Q' then exit the loop. For example

```
while ( true )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter Q to Quit or continue  "); 
    cont = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

    if ( cont == 'Q' ) break;

    //...
```

Take into account that you defined variables `value1` and `value2`  as floats

```
float value1, value2, result= 0;
```

but allow to enter only integer valies.For example

```
value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

I would write the loop the following way

```
while ( true )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Please enter an operator ( +, -, *, / ) or Q to quit: " );   
    op = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

    if ( op == 'Q' ) break;
```